# Conceptual problem concerning differentiation of implicit functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I have the following question concerning the **implicit function theorem** (and, I think, more generally the behavior of a *differential operator*, such as the one used for derivatives).

*[I hope the question does not sound too trivial, but being self-thaught I am often puzzled by what are usually trivial issues]*

> **Implicit Function**
>   We start from an arbitrary implicit function 
>   $$F(x,y)=0$$
>   We assume that $y$ can be expressed as $y=f(x)$, hence we can write
>   $$F(x, f(x))=0.$$
>   Now, if we want to have $\frac{dF}{dx}$ we have
>   $$\require{cancel}\frac{dF}{dx} \equiv F_x \frac{\cancel{dx}}{\cancel{dx}} + F_y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \tag{*}$$
>   which leads to
>   $$ \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}.$$

Fair enough. The question is the following:

Why do we have the $0$ on the RHS of (*)?
*[what I mean is that when we focus on the total derivative of a standard function $F(x,y)$, there is no $0$ anywhere]*
Does it come from the fact that the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ acts basically in the following way:
$$\frac{d}{dx}F(x,f(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}0 \implies F_x + F_y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 ?$$

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: the cancelation above is wrong... what happen is that $\frac{dx}{dx}=1$

Comment: @janmarqz: Thanks a lot. Actually, this is what I meant. Beyond that point, are the remaining things correct? (in particular the very last formula).

Comment: sure, it is good

Comment: @janmarqz Thanks a lot for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use total derivative as below

$$dF(x,y=f(x))=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}dx=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}$$